# How to realize the product of block matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matrices, matlab, products, block-matrices

Given $\mathbf{A}$ is $L\times N$ matrix, and $\mathbf{Q}$ is $NM*M$ matrix which can be divided into $N$ blocks with $M\times M$ size i.e.,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{Q}=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{Q}_1\\
\mathbf{Q}_2\\
\vdots\\
\mathbf{Q}_N
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{Q}_n$ is $n$-th bolck of $\mathbf{Q}$ and is $M\times M$ matrix.

How to perform the following product
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^NA_{1i}\mathbf{Q}_{i}\\
\sum_{i=1}^NA_{2i}\mathbf{Q}_{i}\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{i=1}^NA_{Li}\mathbf{Q}_{i}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
without using `for`, where $A_{\ell i}$ is $(\ell, i)$-th entry of $\mathbf{A}$ and is scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting matrix can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^NA_{1i}\mathbf{I}_M\mathbf{Q}_{i}\\
\sum_{i=1}^NA_{2i}\mathbf{I}_M\mathbf{Q}_{i}\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{i=1}^NA_{Li}\mathbf{I}_M\mathbf{Q}_{i}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}\mathbf{I}_M&\dots&A_{1N}\mathbf{I}_M\\
A_{21}\mathbf{I}_M&\dots&A_{2N}\mathbf{I}_M\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
A_{L1}\mathbf{I}_M&\dots&A_{LN}\mathbf{I}_M\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{Q}_{1}\\
\mathbf{Q}_{2}\\
\vdots\\
\mathbf{Q}_{N}\\
\end{bmatrix}= (\mathbf{A}\otimes \mathbf{I}_M)\mathbf{Q}, 
$$
where $\mathbf{I}_M$ is a $M\times M$ identity matrix, $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html#bt0autl-2_1).

Hence the Matlab code would be like this:

```
kron(a,eye(M))*q
```

Comment: Many thanks! It is very helpful for me.